# click() on classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a dialog using jQuery that opens when an element with a certain class gets clicked. The title should be read from a data

HTML:

```
<div class="clickme" data-dialogtitle="Foo">First Button</div>
<div class="clickme" data-dialogtitle="Bar">Second Button</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});

$(".clickme").click(function () {
  var title = $(this).data("dialogtitle");
  $("#dialog").dialog("option", {title: title});
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

However it tells me $(".clickme").click() isn't a function. How can I fix this?

Comment: You want to do it. You've written some code. So?

Comment: Please formulate a question - detail errors, expected behaviour, actual behaviour, etc.

Comment: What's the issue here?  What is not working?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: *"I want to create a dialog using jQuery..."* You already have: http://jsbin.com/akuge5

Comment: It tells me $(".clickme").click() isn't a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting an error that `$(".clickme").click()` isn't a function, it sounds as though you haven't included jQuery on the page or your code trying to use it is in a `script` tag that's earlier on the page than the script tag containing jQuery.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/akuge5/2) of how your page might load jQuery and jQuery UI. The code itself is verbatim from your question, but this page references the scripts and such. [Here's a second example](http://jsbin.com/akuge5/3/edit) demonstrating the use of [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (indirectly, through the shortcut for it), although if you can just use the first technique (your script at the end of the `body`), that's preferred; [more here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Comment: Oops, don't know what the problem was. Works now. Thanks.